# Can't fetch the entrance Fee from my deployed contract to my frontend component

Tags: solidity, abi, frontend, moralis

**PART OF FREE CODE CAMP BLOCKCHAIN COURSE**

Hey guys I am using react-moralis library to connect with the deployed smart contract.

The smart contract is a Raffle based contract

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/VRFConsumerBaseV2.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/VRFCoordinatorV2Interface.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/KeeperCompatible.sol";

error Raffle__NotEnoughETHEntered();
error Raffle__TransferFailed();
error Raffle__LotteryClosed();
error Raffle__UpkeepNotNeeded(uint256 currentBalance, uint256 numPlayers, uint256 raffleState);

/**
 * @title A Sample Raffle Contract
 * @author Eik
 * @notice This contract is for creating is untamperable decentralized smart contract
 * @dev This implements Chainlink VRF V2 and Chainlink Keepers
 */
contract Raffle is VRFConsumerBaseV2, KeeperCompatible {
    /* Types */
    enum RaffleState {
        OPEN,
        CALCULATING
    }

    /* State Variables */
    uint256 private immutable i_entranceFee;
    address payable[] private s_players;
    //For VRFConsumerBaseV2 Constructor
    VRFCoordinatorV2Interface private immutable i_vrfCoordinator;
    bytes32 private immutable i_gasLane;
    uint64 private immutable i_subscriptionId;
    uint16 private constant REQUEST_CONFIRMATIONS = 3;
    uint32 private immutable i_callbackGasiLimit;
    uint32 private constant NUM_WORDS = 1;

    /* Lottery Variables */
    address private s_recentWinner;
    RaffleState private s_raffleState;
    uint256 private s_lastTimeStamp;
    uint256 private immutable i_interval;

    /* Events */
    event RaffleEnter(address indexed player);
    event RequestedRaffleWinner(uint256 indexed requestId);
    event WinnerPicked(address indexed winner);

    constructor(
        address vrfCoordinatorV2,
        uint256 entranceFee,
        bytes32 gasLane,
        uint64 subscriptionId,
        uint32 callbackGasiLimit,
        uint256 interval
    ) VRFConsumerBaseV2(vrfCoordinatorV2) {
        i_entranceFee = entranceFee;
        i_vrfCoordinator = VRFCoordinatorV2Interface(vrfCoordinatorV2);
        i_gasLane = gasLane;
        i_subscriptionId = subscriptionId;
        i_callbackGasiLimit = callbackGasiLimit;
        s_raffleState = RaffleState.OPEN;
        s_lastTimeStamp = block.timestamp;
        i_interval = interval;
    }

    function enterRaffle() public payable {
        if (msg.value < i_entranceFee) {
            revert Raffle__NotEnoughETHEntered();
        }
        if (s_raffleState != RaffleState.OPEN) {
            revert Raffle__LotteryClosed();
        }
        s_players.push(payable(msg.sender)); //we type cast msg.sender to payable as s_players is payable
        emit RaffleEnter(msg.sender);
    }

    /**
     * @dev This is the function that Chainlink Keeper nodes call as they look for the
     * 'checkUpkeep()' to return true.
     * Following should be true in order to return true:
     * 1. Our time inerval should have passed
     * 2. The lottery should have atleast one player and some ETH
     * 3. Our subscription is funded with LINK
     * 4. Lottery should be in "Open" state
     */
    function checkUpkeep(
        bytes memory /*checkData*/
    ) public override returns (bool upkeepNeeded, bytes memory /*performData*/) {
        bool isOpen = (RaffleState.OPEN == s_raffleState);
        bool timePassed = ((block.timestamp - s_lastTimeStamp) > i_interval);
        bool hasPlayers = (s_players.length > 0);
        bool hasBalance = address(this).balance > 0;
        upkeepNeeded = (isOpen && timePassed && hasPlayers && hasBalance);
    }

    function performUpkeep(bytes calldata /* performData */) external override {
        (bool upkeepNeeded, ) = checkUpkeep("");
        if (!upkeepNeeded) {
            revert Raffle__UpkeepNotNeeded(
                address(this).balance,
                s_players.length,
                uint256(s_raffleState)
            );
        }
        s_raffleState = RaffleState.CALCULATING;
        uint256 requestId = i_vrfCoordinator.requestRandomWords(
            i_gasLane,
            i_subscriptionId,
            REQUEST_CONFIRMATIONS,
            i_callbackGasiLimit,
            NUM_WORDS
        );
        emit RequestedRaffleWinner(requestId);
    }

    function fulfillRandomWords(
        uint256 /* requestId */,
        uint256[] memory randomWords
    ) internal override {
        uint256 indexOfWinner = randomWords[0] % s_players.length;
        address payable recentWinner = s_players[indexOfWinner];
        s_recentWinner = recentWinner;
        s_raffleState = RaffleState.OPEN;
        s_players = new address payable[](0);
        s_lastTimeStamp = block.timestamp;
        (bool success, ) = recentWinner.call{value: address(this).balance}("");
        if (!success) {
            revert Raffle__TransferFailed();
        }
        emit WinnerPicked(recentWinner);
    }

    /* Getter Functions */
    function getEntranceFee() public view returns (uint256) {
        return i_entranceFee;
    }

    function getPlayer(uint256 index) public view returns (address payable) {
        return s_players[index];
    }

    function getRecenetWinner() public view returns (address) {
        return s_recentWinner;
    }

    function getRaffleState() public view returns (RaffleState) {
        return s_raffleState;
    }

    function getNumWords() public pure returns (uint256) {
        return NUM_WORDS;
    }

    function getNumOfPlayers() public view returns (uint256) {
        return s_players.length;
    }

    function getLatestTimeStamp() public view returns (uint256) {
        return s_lastTimeStamp;
    }

    function getRequestConfirmations() public pure returns (uint256) {
        return REQUEST_CONFIRMATIONS;
    }

    function getInterval() public view returns (uint256) {
        return i_interval;
    }
}
```

In my component I am trying to fetch the entrance fee from my function but I am unable to do so as it returns undefined. I am getting the chainId and the raffleAddress correctly so I think the issue is in the getEntranceFee() function.

```
import { useWeb3Contract, useMoralis } from "react-moralis"
import { abi, contractAddress } from "../constants/index.js"
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import { ethers } from "ethers"

export default function LotteryEnterance() {
    const { isWeb3Enabled, chainId: chainIdHex, enableWeb3 } = useMoralis()
    const [chainId, setChainId] = useState(null)
    const [fee, setFee] = useState("0")

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!isWeb3Enabled) {
            enableWeb3()
        }
    }, [isWeb3Enabled, enableWeb3])

    useEffect(() => {
        if (chainIdHex) {
            const chainIdDecimal = parseInt(chainIdHex, 16)
            setChainId(chainIdDecimal)
            console.log(chainIdDecimal)
        }
    }, [chainIdHex])

    const raffleAddress = chainId in contractAddress ? contractAddress[chainId][0] : null

    //runContractFunction can both send transactions and read states
    const { runContractFunction: enterRaffle } = useWeb3Contract({
        abi: abi,
        contractAddress: raffleAddress,
        functionName: "enterRaffle",
        params: {},
        msgValue: fee,
    })

    const { runContractFunction: getEntranceFee } = useWeb3Contract({
        abi: abi,
        contractAddress: raffleAddress,
        functionName: "getEntranceFee",
        params: {},
    })

    //PROBLEM HERE 
    async function updateUI() {
        const feeFromCall = (await getEntranceFee()).toString()
        setFee(feeFromCall)
        console.log(fee)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if (isWeb3Enabled) {
            updateUI()
        }
    }, [isWeb3Enabled])

    return (
        <div>
            This project was made by Sarthak
            <div>Entrance Fee : {fee} ETH</div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

My contract address :
`{ "11155111": ["0xcD31ECC318Ec7b0Dae58fCFE112cCA6cF2A5E882"] }`

Comment: Are you sure that you set the entrance fee when you deployed the contract?  Which network is your contract deployed on?

Comment: I deployed the contract on sepolia and localhost both. And yes I've set the entrance fee

Comment: I think it's the common problem of usestate taking some time to update. You can check these answers for a solution https://stackoverflow.com/q/54069253/19062779